# Detecting which uiscrollview user touches

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have an iPad application in which two scroll views are next to each other. I have UiImages inside of both so i need to know where the user touches whether it's the first scroll view or the second one. Is there any way i can track user's touch position whether he hits the scrollview A or B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add UITapGestureRecognizer to your scrollviews, like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGuestureForA = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureCapturedForA:)];
[scrollViewA addGestureRecognizer:tapGuestureForA];
```

same thing can be done for scrollView B, and when tapGestureCapturedForA is called, it indicates user touched scrollView A.

Comment: thank you for your reply..ur answer covered my question thank u